# A proper class for smooth chaotic function

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, intuition, definitions, analytic-functions, chaos

This might be a little, soft, but I'll try

Consider the interval $I=[-1,1]$. We will define a **chaotic function** $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \times I  \to \mathbb{C}$ in the following traditional way:

For every $M>0$ and $\delta >0$ there exsist two points $x,y \in I$ with $|x- y | < \delta$, and a time $T>0$ such that $|f(T,x)  - f(T,y)| >M$.

We would also like to demand **smoothness** in $I$, so that *at least* for some $[0,T) \subseteq \mathbb{R}_+$ we have that $f$ is analytic in $[0,T)\times I$.

**My question** is what is the traditional way, or the most adequate way, to define smooth chaotic function? Can $f$ be analytic? a limit of analytic functions? Can we demand that for every $t\in \mathbb{R}_+$, $f(t,\cdot)\in C^{\infty}(I)$?